# Flags in all faces in rubik cubes

Tags: rubiks-cube, flags

Anyone knows if it is possible to obtain a diferent country flag in all six faces of the Rubik Cube?

Thanks

Comment: Another interesting question may be: what is the maximum number of flags that can be created on the faces of a rubik's cube?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To start off, we can reduce the number of flags to look at with some simple deductions.

The only national flags able to be made on a rubik's cube, would be ones of either 3 horizontal or vertical stripes, with no "extra" pieces (No stars, no crowns, whatever), and can only use the Rubik's cube colours, those being Blue, Yellow, Green, Red, Orange, and White OR Black (Depending on the style of Rubik's cube).

*EDIT: Cross flags could be used as well, with 2 usable ones on a Rubik's Cube, England and Dominican Republic (Other cross flags are "scandinavian crosses" which are off-center and so could not be represented on a Rubik's cube.)*

With this, we can limit down the number of possible flags to

> 23 (Using White) or 11 (Using Black) (May have missed some, but I think this is correct.)

We can limit it some more however, since the center square of each Rubik's cube's face cannot be changed, we know exactly 1 flag must have a white center stripe, exactly 1 flag must have a blue center stripe, etc.

Looking through the flags, we find that

> No national flag has an orange center stripe. This makes it impossible to have a flag on the face with the orange center square.

So the answer to the question is

> No. It is impossible to re-arrange a Rubik's Cube to have 6 national flags shown on the 6 faces.

Comment: With some artistic liberty (especially if your cube's plastic is white), you could use the orange centre to make the flag of [Niger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_of_Niger).

Comment: True, certain other flags could be used with artistic liberty, but Niger is the only one who could help orange, leaving 5 orange squares which couldn't be separated into flags (there would always be 2 left over). Random leftover squares is one of the reasons why I removed artistic liberty, so only striped/cross flags could be used.